# Entry point x which is required by y doesn't exists

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I trying to add service to my package.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocaleService {}
```

export it in the api file -

```
export * from './src/locale.service';
```

and trying to using it in some component in the package -

```
export class FormComponent {
  constructor(private localeService: LocaleService) {}
}
```

When I publish it I got error -

```
ERROR: Entry point swagular/components/src/locale.service which is required by swagular/components doesn't exists.
An unhandled exception occurred: Entry point swagular/components/src/locale.service which is required by swagular/components doesn't exists.
```

source code is [here](https://github.com/yantrab/swagular/tree/master/projects/swagular/components)

Answer (score 2):

My ide was auto added import like this - `import { LocaleService } from 'swagular/components/src/locale.service';`

and ng-packager lib thinks that it is a module.

change it to `import { LocaleService } from '../locale.service';` solve the probelm.